# Create a table-like structure to bind to a DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, datagridview

I have a class that stores data in a `DataTable` to make it easier to bind it to a `DataGridView`. However, I found out that the `DataTable` has too much overhead and consumes too much CPU time.

I'd like to replace it with a more specialized table-like structure with less complexity to speed things up. But it has to be possible to bind it to a `DataGridView`. There's no need for editing, adding or removing data through a `DataGridView`.

This is a very basic attempt to show what I try to do:

```
public class SimpleTable
{
    private Dictionary<string, Type> columns;
    private List<object[]> rowList;

    public SimpleTable()
    {
        columns = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
        rowList = new List<object[]>();
        columns.Add("Column1", typeof(string));
        columns.Add("Column2", typeof(double));
        columns.Add("Column3", typeof(double));
    }

    public void AddRow(params object[] values)
    {
        // do some checks
        rowList.Add(values);
    }

    public object Item
    {
        get
        {
            return rowList[rowIndex][columnIndex];
        }
        set
        {
            rowList[rowIndex][columnIndex] = value;
        }
    }

    public List<object[]> Rows
    {
        get
        {
            return rowList;
        }
    }
}
```

In the picture below (upper half)  you can see how the data is shown when I bind the `Rows` property to a DGV. This is not what I want, but the lower half.

[image]

How do I have to design the class to be shown as a "table" in a `DataGridView`?

Comment: No need to use rowList.  You can use dt.AsEnumerable().Select((x,i) new{"Row #" + i, x.Field<double>("LongLength"), x.Field<double>("SyncfRoot")).ToList();

Comment: A DataTable is just a collection - with typed data as opposed to `List<object)`! - so it is hard to imagine it consuming CPU unless code is interacting with it.  Seems a bit XYish

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp In my old class I use `dt.Rows(rowIndex)(columnIndex) = value` to set the values inside the `DataTable`. Diagnostic tools tell me that is uses 40% of the CPU time.

Comment: Poking data into a DataTable RxR and CxC is suboptimal. A List<T> would probably be more appropriate than either a DataTable or that thing being built.  Maybe a `BindingList<T>` or even a `SortableBindingList<T>`

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp This is what I try to do. But this means my T has to offer every column as a property like "Column1", "Column2" and "Column3". In this special case I need two different sets of columns (one has 8 columns, the other one has more). Sure I could create two classes, but isn't there a more dynamic way?

Comment: @keco you have a good idia .

Comment: I am not understanding what exactly what you are asking. I would think that using a `List<T>` for this, especially if… _”There's no need for editing, adding or removing data through a DataGridView”_ … would be the way to go. Making a `DataTable` from the `List<T>` seems like a waste of effort unless there something else needed. I am not sure if I follow what you mean by…

Comment: _“But this means my T has to offer every column as a property like "Column1", "Column2" and "Column3". In this special case I need two different sets of columns (one has 8 columns, the other one has more). Sure I could create two classes, but isn't there a more dynamic way?”_ ?

Comment: If you need Two (2) different sets of columns for the SAME `List<T>` then I would suggest the code "manually" create the columns in the grid. Set the grids `AutoGenerateColumns` property to false. Then create two methods that add the desired columns you want. In each method you can use each column’s `DataPropertyName` to map which property you want the column to display. I am pretty sure you can clear the columns and add different columns without changing the data source. I am guessing I may be missing something.

Comment: If your program is only using 40% CPU then it means you have 60% spare, so clearly it's not working hard enough!  If it was maxing out then maybe that would be an issue but really it seems like you're microoptimizing here. Just use a DataSet to design a strongly typed datatable, then you have your object, and it's bindable.. the end. If you have complaints about the speed of loading, learn why it's so slow (maybe  you're raising change events and redrawing a UI every time you add a value)

Comment: @CaiusJard The 40% is the measurement of this one single line of code. I measured the complete algorithm of parsing a file, converting types and assigning them to the `DataTable` and this one lines used 40% of the CPU time. There is no events or UI related stuff going on. Data is bound to a `DataGridView` when the algorithm is finished. I replaced the `DataTable` with a `List<T>` and now the whole algorithm only needs 1/3 of the time.

Comment: So you saved a couple of milliseconds of production, code optimized CPU time? And what you generated didn't meet the requirements, so by the time you've finished turning it into something that does, you'll have reinvented a large part of a DataTable, and the program may never pay back in terms of CPU time saved, the amount of time it took to develop? It might be helpful to put some context onto this, and show us the code that takes the massive amount of time/resources; DataTable maybe catching your ire over something for which it isn't fully responsible..